# Solving for two functions defined recursively

Tags: equation-solving, functions, difference-equations

[image: Problem]

How would I be able to find the equations for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Comment: Is this a math question or a question specifically about the software Mathematica? If you have a math question, take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to do it with mathematica

Answer (score 1):

```
sol = RSolve[{f[n + 1] == 2*f[n] + 3 g[n] + 2 n, f[1] == 4, 
g[n + 1] == 2 g[n] + 3 f[n] + 5, g[1] == 9}, {f[n], g[n]}, n]

(f[n] - g[n]) /. sol[[1]] /. n -> 2005

(*1999*)
```